# Adding jQuery table-edits plugin to my rails 5 app

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to improve a rails app I'm developing. So far, I have pages that show the tables that I have in my database. But, I want to use the table-edits jQuery plugin to make these actually editable while using the website. I am just very confused as to how to get this done. I am rather new to web development, so I am having a rough time figuring it out on my own.

http://nathancahill.github.io/table-edits/

As of now, I have the table-edits.js file in app/assets/javascripts, and I added the `//= require table-edits` statement inside the `application.js` file. I am stuck here, and I am not sure what exactly to do next.

My `index.html.erb` looks like this:

```
<div id="page-wrapper">
    <div id="main-wrapper">
        <div id="main-content">
    <div class="title">
            <h3>Hello</h3>
    </div>
        <%= render partial:  'my_table', locals: {table:@table} %>
    </div>
```

This webpage displays the table. And I would like to be able to edit the values. TIA!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like it was just not compatible with Datatables.js. For anyone wondering, editable-table works!

http://mindmup.github.io/editable-table/